# How to replace code of the method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have a library and it's required to change a code of the method. But I can't change a code of the library. How to replace code of the method outside the library's code?

Comment: I dind't try but think it should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229991/how-to-replace-objective-c-2-0-class-method-implementation-in-runtime?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you'll want to do Method Swizzling.

Since Objective-C uses message passing, method swizzling is the process of modifying the mapping between the name of the method (the selector) with it's implementation.

[This page has information on how to perform Method Swizzling](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling).

Comment: I have tried this. It doesn't work. Method servers protocol on the parent class. Can't use local ivar and class global variables too. Many problems and no result at all:(